# Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to navigate with NavigationActions, but for some reason it won't navigate.
I'm trying to move from LoginScreen to HomeScreen.

loginscreen:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      status: '',
    }

    this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this)
  }

  handlePress(){
    firebaseRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
      //Success, move to homepage.
      const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
        ]
      })

      this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction) <-- SAYS NAVIGATION IS UNDEFINED 
    }).catch(function(error){
      //Failed to log in, print error.
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
```

this is where I call handlePress:

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.logBtn} onPress={()=>this.handlePress()}>
  <Text style={styles.logTxt}>
  Login
  </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is 'navigation'(in render method, loginscreen):

```
const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;
```

this is app.js where I set the navigation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import LoginScreen from './app/screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './app/screens/RegisterScreen';
import HomeScreen from './app/screens/HomeScreen';
import FriendsScreen from './app/screens/FriendsScreen';

const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login:{
     screen: LoginScreen,
     navigationOptions: ({navigation}) =>({
       header: null,
     }),
  },
  Register:{
      screen: RegisterScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) =>({
        header: null,
      }),
  },
  Home:{
    screen: TabNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
              size={26}
              style={{ color: tintColor }}
            />
          )
        }),
      },
      Friends: {
        screen: FriendsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Friends',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Ionicons
              name={focused ? 'ios-people' : 'ios-people-outline'}
              size={26}
              style={{ color: tintColor }}
            />
          )
        }),
      },
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#553A91"},
      headerTitleStyle: {color: "#FFFFFF"},
    }),
  }
});
export default Stylelist;
```

I tried to log the error from the 'catch' and I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
const { navigate} = this.props.navigation;
```

or

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

Actually, what you get in props is navigation object, which has navigate method in it.And what you were doing was

```
const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;
```

This gets evaluates to

```
this.props.navigation.navigation
```

It says look for navigation property inside navigation object, which actually is not present, hence giving `undefined`. I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Can you please explain more / give me an information source why this is working like that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your function is bind with this.

```
onPress={()=>this.handlePress()}
```

instead

```
onPress={()=>this.handlePress.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
Of course I had used `setTimeout`. There may be someone who has this problem, so it's a good reminder.

only use `let that = this;`

```
componentDidMount() {
    let that = this ;
    setTimeout(function () {
        let toHome = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'MainScreen'})]
        });
        that.props.navigation.dispatch(toHome);
    },3000);
}
```